# Count and association eager loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there an effective way to get count of records while eager loading associations?
`Post.includes({:comments => :author}).count` produces `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) ... LEFT OUTER JOIN ...` which is far from optimal. Maybe some pagination plugin does it in a clever way?

EDT [Kaminari gem](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) is able to do it properly, although only for named scopes.

Comment: So, you want to do eager loading, but have rails NOT eager load and instead just give you the count?  Why not just ask for the count in the first place?  Sorry if i've misunderstood...can you give a more realistic example?

Comment: @Max Well, count of posts doesn't depend on what associations are loaded. The example is entirely realistic - I have different predicates in different actions but the view is the same, so the same associations should be loaded. So, to keep it DRY i have `before_filter { @posts = Post.include(...) }` . In action I have something like `@posts = @posts.where(...); @pages = @posts.count / @@items_per_page`

Comment: So you've already loaded the @posts by the time you want to know how many there are?  Then just do @posts.size.  I think i'm misunderstanding you still.  Can you edit your OP with all of the relevant code from your controller and what you want to do?

Comment: @Max They aren't loaded. This is a simple paging scenario, I need the total number of posts conforming to some predicate and then I need to load them with associations, limit and offset.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [count_by_sql](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-count_by_sql)?

Comment: The whole point of the question is to avoid the use of arbitrary SQL